# Some IBM P8 ChoiceLists are incorrect when being returned via CMIS

Tags: cmis, filenet-p8

Facing with strange behavior of the FileNet Choice Lists when they are being returned through CMIS.

There are

IntList in FEM:
 [image: FEM IntList]

and IntList_Test 
[image]

---

first one is bound to both MultiInteger and MultiSelectedInteger property templates
[image]

---

There is a Document Class called "Multi" that contains those property templates with correct choice list (IntList):
[image]

---

Despite this fact CMIS Workbench shows incorrect choices for MultiSelectedInteger:

[image]

and correct ones for MultiInteger:
[image]

So, i can't understand why. It seems that there's some invisible connection between MultiSelectedInteger and IntList_Test. Moreover, working via WSI\EJB connection there's no such problems. 
Probably there's some bug at CMIS navigator "Proxy" (.war deployment) side.

Also it's ok when i put values from IntList and it argues when i try to put value from offered choice list (IntList_Test):

[image]

---

Any help is appreciated.